# C Program to find union of area of 2 rectangles

Tags: c

I was trying to solve 'RECTMEET' problem of codebuddy. I wrote this code:

```
int main(void) {
    int x11, x12, x21, x22, y11, y12, y21, y22, a1, a2, a3;
    scanf("%d", &x11);
    scanf("%d", &y11);
    scanf("%d", &x12);
    scanf("%d", &y12);  
    scanf("%d", &x21);
    scanf("%d", &y21);
    scanf("%d", &x22);
    scanf("%d", &y22);
    a1 = (x12 - x11) * (y12 - y11);
    a2 = (x22 - x21) * (y22 - y21);
    if (x21 >= x11 && x21 <= x12 && y21 >= y11 && y21 <= y12) {
        a3 = (x12 - x21) * (y12 - y21);
    } else
    if (x22 >= x11 && x22 <= x12 && y22 >= y11 && y22 <= y12) {
        a3 = (x22 - x11) * (y22 - y11);
    } else {
        a3 = 0;
    }
    printf("%d", a1 + a2 - a3);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried many cases and I got right answers for all of them but when I submit this solution I get a wrong answer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First: `#include <stdio.h>` and `printf("%d\n", a1+a2-a3);`

Comment: `0 0 3 3 1 1 2 2` should return area 16, your code returns 6!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem can be solved using the sweep line algorithm. But according your code, let's take another thought. The area of union of two rectangles is make the sum of the two rectangles first, then subtract the intersection area from the sum. So, how to calculate the intersection area?

It's impossible to have an intersection area in the following four situation.

1. A2 is totally on the right hand side of A1 ( i.e. if( x21 >= x12 )
2. A2 is totally on the left hand side of A1 ( i.e. if( x22 <= x11 )
3. A2 is totally on the top of A1 ( i.e. if( y21 >= y12 )
4. A2 is totally on the bottom of A1 ( i.e. if( y22 <= y11 )

Now It's time to consider intersected condition.

width of A1 = WA1 = x12 - x11

width of A2 = WA2 = x22 - x21

==> width of intersection area, W = ( WA1 + WA2 - ( left hand side diff ) - ( right hand side diff ) ) / 2

i.e. W = ( (x12 - x11) + (x22 - x21) - abs(x21 - x11) - abs(x22 - x12) ) / 2

and height of intersection area, H = ( HA1 + HA2 - ( top hand side diff ) - ( bottom hand side diff ) ) / 2

i.e. H = ( (y12 - y11) + (y22 - y21) - abs(y21 - y11) - abs(y22 - y12) ) / 2

Then the area of intersection is W*H

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int x11, x12, x21, x22, y11, y12, y21, y22, a1, a2, a3;
    scanf("%d", &x11);
    scanf("%d", &y11);
    scanf("%d", &x12);
    scanf("%d", &y12);
    scanf("%d", &x21);
    scanf("%d", &y21);
    scanf("%d", &x22);
    scanf("%d", &y22);
    a1 = (x12 - x11) * (y12 - y11);
    a2 = (x22 - x21) * (y22 - y21);
    if (x21 >= x12 || x22 <= x11 || y21 >= y12 || y22 <= y11) {
        a3 = 0;
    } else {
        a3 = (x12 - x11 + x22 - x21 - abs(x21 - x11) - abs(x22 - x12)) / 2 *
             (y12 - y11 + y22 - y21 - abs(y21 - y11) - abs(y22 - y12)) / 2;
    }
    printf("%d", a1 + a2 - a3);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my score [image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider x and y seperately. Each of them is classified into 6 cases as follows.

- x21 ≦ x11

  - x21 ≦ x22 ≦ x11 ≦ x12 (no overlap)
  - x21 ≦ x11 ≦ x22 ≦ x12 (partial overlap)
  - x21 ≦ x11 ≦ x12 ≦ x22 (rectangle 2 contains rectangle 1)
- x11 ≦ x21 ≦ x12

  - x11 ≦ x21 ≦ x22 ≦ x12 (rectangle 2 inside rectangle 1)
  - x11 ≦ x21 ≦ x12 ≦ x22 (partial overlap)
- x12 ≦ x21

  - x11 ≦ x12 ≦ x21 ≦ x22 (no overlap)

---

It's a bother to treat them individually. I prefer calculating the overlap area in a uniform way.

```
x31 = max(x11, x21)
x32 = min(x12, x22)
y31 = max(y11, y21)
y32 = min(y12, y22)
a3 = max(0, x32 - x31) * max(0, y32 - y31)
```